# What is the difference between PyBytes_Type and PyString_Type

Tags: python, string, unicode, python-c-api

It appears that Python 2 has PyString_Type whereas Python 3 has PyBytes_Type

What is going on under the hood?

I'm writing a C++ wrapper (currently wrapping Python3, but I hope to add Python2 support later), and I just got round to the task of wrapping strings.

Is it correct that 2&3 both provide separate support for a byte-string and a Unicode-string, but they have just done some renaming?

If this is so then is this table correct?:

```
Py2 byte-string ~ PyString_Type             Py2 Unicode-string ~ PyUnicode_Type 
Py3 byte-string ~ PyBytes_Type              Py3 Unicode-string ~ ?
```

And if so, how to complete it?

EDIT: [Python2 doc for String](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/string.html) says:

> ***These functions have been renamed to PyBytes_* in Python 3.x***. Unless
>   otherwise noted, the PyBytes functions available in 3.x are aliased to
>   their PyString_* equivalents to help porting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2, `str` contains bytes (and the type `bytes == str`) and `unicode` contains Unicode strings. Therefore 2.x has three types effectively.

In Python 3, `bytes` contains bytes and `str` contains Unicode strings. The `str` type in 3.x is the `unicode` type of 2.x. Therefore 3.x has two types effectively. This is the conceptual approach that you should take and any 2.x-related work should also separate Unicode strings and bytes in this way.

Based on [this section](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/cporting.html?highlight=pystring#str-unicode-unification) in the documentation that means `PyUnicode` is used in both 2.x and 3.x for the Unicode strings. `PyBytes` is used for byte-strings in both and the `PyString` type only has meaning in Python 2.x.